# How can I insert a string into quotations while keeping the string input in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.11

```
Random = (random.choice(Usernames))
print (str (Random))
studio.invite_curator (Random)
```

Text input in quotations is needed to complete the last line, yet I have a string that I need in the quotations. Is there any way to keep the quotations and the string in a new string variable?

This is just a piece of code from my project, but I know there are not any problems with the other parts I do not have shown.

I tried to use this script:

```
Random2 = '"',Random,'"'
studio.invite_curator (Random2)
```

But outputted as an error, because the final line of what I showed above needs to be in quotations. I can not yet find a way to work around this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to concatenate three strings?

Comment: I need to keep the quotations but have a string inside the variable.

Comment: You are saying "keep" the quotations, but it's not clear that you *have* actual quote characters in your string. It seems like you are talking about quote characters that are part of the python syntax. If you have a variable like `test = "hello"` the quotes are not part of the string. You can add quotes to it a number of ways (like `print('"' + test +'"')`). Buy you are not keeping quotes, you are *adding* quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation instead of commas.

```
Random2 = '"' + Random + '"'
```

Comment: Tried it just now... Still doesn't work. The final parenthesis have to have quotations or it won't work -_-

Comment: @FazeDex I don't understand what "final parenthesis have to have quotations" means.  Can you give an actual example please.

Comment: It needs quotations around it, or I get an extremely long error message

Comment: studio.invite_curator (Random) - I'm talking about these parenthesis here

Comment: @FazeDex  Calling a function requires parentheses after the function name.  Those parentheses are part of the function call.  They have nothing to do with the actual value of `Random`.  I am still confused what you actually mean.  Perhaps you could show the actual error message.

Comment: It's too long to post... It is too long by 1.2k characters

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py",

Comment: line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scratchattach\_studio.py", line 142, in invite_curator
    ).json()
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/miche/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Files/Invite_Curators.py", line 24, in <module>
    studio.invite_curator ('"' + Random +'"')
  File "C:\Users\miche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scratchattach\_studio.py", line 144, in invite_curator
    raise(_exceptions.Unauthorized)
scratchattach._exceptions.Unauthorized

Comment: Tried to change a little bit, and got this error message: 
 
NameError: name 'KatMasters' is not defined. *KatMasters Is the value of KM, I swapped out KM with Random*

Comment: Edit the question and include the error there.  This is way too long to post as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new string variable Random2 which contains the value of Random enclosed in quotation marks.
Alternatively you could use f-strings to insert the variable into the string.

```
Random2 = f'"{Random}"'
studio.invite_curator(Random2)
```

This will also create a new string variable Random2 which contains the value of Random enclosed in quotation marks.